# How to serilize/deserilize Json Object to C# class

Tags: c#, json, object, serialization, deserialization

I have two json responses that have "resultObject" property. One of them has returned object, other one has returned string/bool.

I have a C# object that use from JSON.

```
public class UseInboxResult
{      

    public string version { get; set; }
    public bool resultStatus { get; set; }
    public int resultCode { get; set; }
    public string resultMessage { get; set; }
    public ResultObject resultObject { get; set; }
}

public class ResultObject
{        
    public string access_token { get; set; }
    public int expires_in { get; set; }
    public string token_type { get; set; }


    public int displayCount { get; set; }
    public int totalCount { get; set; }

    public List<Items> items { get; set; }
}
```

JSON Objects has different types of resultObject property

```
    //First
{
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "resultStatus": true,
  "resultCode": 200,
  "resultMessage": "Your operation has been completed successfully.",
  "resultObject": {
    "displayCount": 1,
    "totalCount": 1,
    "items": [
      {
        "id": "5db72eec92b565000100a0aa",
        "createTime": "2019-10-28T18:09:48.924Z",
        "updateTime": "2019-12-20T18:10:41.451Z",
        "displayName": "John Doe",
        "email": "john.doe@example.com",
        "activation": true,
        "notifyDedicatedIps": null
      }
    ]
  }
}

//Second

{
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "resultStatus": false,
  "resultCode": 200,
  "resultMessage": "OK",
  "resultObject": "5e0491bdaf6d250001834b75"
}
```

How to bind a c# class for this property.

Comment: Do you know which one of those you're receiving? Does it depend on what call you're making or where you're reading from? Or is it just the resultStatus that defines it?

Comment: if `resultStatus: true` then you have your expected result otherwise return 404 or error?

Comment: Both of the jsons comes from different servis url. @Dunning-Kruger one of them string, bool and the others kind of object

Comment: @D.Dahlberg i am not interested in result Status:true because, these are sample json objects and i use different api link from same project  which is https://reference.useinbox.com/?version=latest#de7b85b3-599d-a2de-423b-75016880b2bf

Comment: @MertMetin Updated my answer. Thank you!

Comment: @MertMetin "5e0491bdaf6d250001834b75" looks like a contactid.. since you know what the request is returning then you should have classes to match. They're clearly stated in your api doc. There's no autoresolve type. if you just want to have one class and know exactly what you're getting then you can use object or dynamic as property type

Answer (score 1):

You can split them into separate parts with a generic.

```cs
public class Response<T>
where T : class
{      

    public string version { get; set; }
    public bool resultStatus { get; set; }
    public int resultCode { get; set; }
    public T resultMessage { get; set; }
}

public class ResultObject
{        
    // Your same ResultObject.
}
```

You can now deserialize into `Response<ResultObject>` or `Response<string>` depending on what you're calling.

Comment: As i mentioned above these json objects are samples, if i got success response, it is true

Comment: `resultMessage` is `true`? Then just use `Response<bool>`.

Comment: I solved my problem.I used similar to above class structure but result object's type is an object not generic class

Answer (score 0):

You can replace `ResultObject` with `object` then check the `resultStatus`
if `resultStatus == true` deserialize the `resultObject` to an `ResultObject`.
else deserialize the `resultObject` to `string`

```cs
public class UseInboxResult
{      
    public string version { get; set; }
    public bool resultStatus { get; set; }
    public int resultCode { get; set; }
    public string resultMessage { get; set; }
    public object resultObject { get; set; }//<--NOTE THIS
}
```

```cs
var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UseInboxResult>(json);
//var data = System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.Deserialize<UseInboxResult>(json); .Net Core 3
if (data.resultStatus == true)
{
      ResultObject result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResultObject>(data.resultObject.ToString());
}
else
{
    string result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResultObject>(data.resultObject.ToString());
}
```

Comment: i am not interested in result Status:true because, these are sample json objects and i use different api link from same project @Farhad

Comment: Newtonsoft.Json is the most helpful for me because of the ResultObject can be parseable json string and use any kind of object type. However i did not use the if statement